# Comando remove() en listas de python

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo python, y tengo que hacer un programa donde pide al usuario escribir 5 elementos de una lista, y posteriormente mostrarlos. Así también preguntar si se desea eliminar o agregar un elemento a la lista. Todo mi código corre bien, solamente cuando se quiere eliminar un elemento, y se ingresa el nombre de, me dice que hay un error, y que el elemento x de remove no existe.
Si alguien puede ayudarme pls, no sé que estoy haciendo mal

```
elementos: list[str] = [input('Escriba 5 elementos cualesquiera: ')]
print(elementos)

elemento = (input('¿Desea agregar o eliminar algun elemento de dicha lista?: '))
if elemento == "agregar":
    elementos.append(input("Por favor agregue otro elemento: "))
    print(elementos)

elif elemento == "eliminar":
    elementos.remove(input("Por favor escriba el elemento que quiera eliminar: "))
    print(elementos)

elif elemento == "ninguno":
    print("Gracias por participar, vuelva pronto. Hasta luego.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

En tu código, por el momento al solicitar los 5 elementos los estas guardando como un solo `string`, por ejemplo, si ingresas `1 2 3 4 5` al imprimir los elementos te va a dar

```
['1 2 3 4 5']
```

Es importante ver que todos los elementos están en un único `string` y por lo tanto al eliminar, si deseas hacer por ejemplo `remove(2)` te va a mandar error

Para corregirlo puedes utilizar los métodos `map()` y `split()` para que la entrada se divida en diferentes índices en tu lista `elementos`

```
elementos = input('Escriba 5 elementos cualesquiera: ').split()
```

Ejemplo completo

```
elementos = input('Escriba 5 elementos cualesquiera: ').split()

elemento = (input('¿Desea agregar o eliminar algun elemento de dicha lista?: '))
if elemento == "agregar":
    elementos.append(input("Por favor agregue otro elemento: "))
    print(elementos)

elif elemento == "eliminar":
    elementos.remove(input("Por favor escriba el elemento que quiera eliminar: "))
    print(elementos)

elif elemento == "ninguno":
    print("Gracias por participar, vuelva pronto. Hasta luego.")
```

Ejemplo de ejecución (Nota como ahora al imprimirse `elementos` cada valor es un índice diferente de la lista

```
Escriba 5 elementos cualesquiera:  1 2 3 4 5
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
¿Desea agregar o eliminar algun elemento de dicha lista?:  eliminar
Por favor escriba el elemento que quiera eliminar:  3
['1', '2', '4', '5']
```

Comment: No entiendo por que conviertes en cadena cada item de la lista devuelta por el metodo split. Split ya de por si devuelve una lista de cadenas.

Comment: Ah, es que primero pense que los elementos serían solo números enteros y convertía todo a `int`, pero luego pensé que el op tal vez querría utilizar cualquier cosa como valor de entrada y solo sustituí el `int` por el `str`. Gracias por la nota, ahora lo cambio

Comment: De nada! Ahora una cosa más, estás convirtiendo a lista lo que ya es una lista.

Comment: Rezagos de utilizar `map` haha, gracias, ya lo cambié

Comment: De nada compañero c: